# Google Cloud Messaging Server Side Code in C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging

I want to write implement 3rd party server for GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for android using .Net. The official documentation gives guidelines for using it with servlet-api and gcm-server.jar ( Java helper for server side ).

Is there any equivalent for using it in C#?

Answer (score 7):

The Google Cloud Messaging Client Library has been ported to C#:
https://github.com/Redth/GCMSharp

The same developer has produced a library for sending server-side push notifications to iOS, Android, Windows Phone, and Blackberry:
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: I started creating another repo for server-side push functions here https://github.com/fireydude/GCM_Sender

Answer (score 0):

If you're not keen on rewriting the whole thing, perhaps [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) will help? It is a Java virtual machine for .NET and has tools for Java-.NET interoperability as well.

Hope this helps!