# Does google have a sample for gcm server in Asp.Net?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) server in Asp.Net. Is there any sample about it? I was looking for it in Android SDK folders but there is no sample for .Net?

Does any boy know a .Net sample?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14293642/115145

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543527/google-cloud-messaging-server-side-code-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class AndroidGCMPushNotification
{
    public AndroidGCMPushNotification()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
    {
        string GoogleAppID = "GGOGLE_API_KEY";        
        var SENDER_ID = "SENDER_ID/PROJECT_NUMBER";
        var value = message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&
        delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + 
        System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
}
```

You can call SendNotification function by passing device Id and Message.

```
AndroidGCMPushNotification apnGCM = new AndroidGCMPushNotification();

string strResponse =
apnGCM.SendNotification("DEVICE_ID",
"Test Push Notification message ");
```

Comment: @Najj Makhoul itried this but i got an error 401: Unauthorised  how to handle with this

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake at this line:

```
 string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&
    delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + 
    System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
```

"&" is missing before parameter registration_id, so **&registration_id** is correct.

Sample works perfectly. Just make sure to put you Server Key at:

```
string GoogleAppID = "GGOGLE_API_KEY";
```